# How to stop aws ses mail queue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Due to a bug in our application, one of our testing servers started spamming mail orders to AWS SES. We believe that these mails have been put into a queue, as the mail receiver keeps getting around 1 - 2 mails per second, and is not stopping.

The SES console doesn't show real time sent mails, so we are still figuring out how many mails have been sent to the queue.

Is there a way to stop this behaviour? We use the same SES for the production application, and we fear we might runnout of mails to send. How can the "queue" be cancelled?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/12/08/delete-all-messages-in-an-amazon-sqs-queue/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS has a built-in queue purging function.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_PurgeQueue.html

```
https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/123456789012/MyQueue/
?Action=PurgeQueue
&Expires=2020-12-12T22%3A52%3A43PST
&Version=2012-11-05
&AUTHPARAMS
```

Comment: Just in case anyone went through this again, you can also do it via CLI:
aws sqs purge-queue --queue-url https:/example.com

Comment: How to use this with SES? I run into the same issue but I wouldn't know what to put instead of `MyQueue`