# Clear AWS SES email queue

Tags: django, amazon-ses

My Django server ran into an error during the night and sent me thousands upon thousands of error logs by emails (several per second). I patched the error and rebooted the server, but I am still receiving emails, dated from several hours ago.

How can I stop the old emails from being sent? Is there a way to tell amazon SES to clear its queue of email?

Comment: Does [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58229901/how-to-stop-aws-ses-mail-queue) help you?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. I checked it and even commented for more info, without success.

Comment: Looking at the [SES-API actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html) it doesn't look good - I'd create a support ticket, maybe they can purge the backlog on their end or set the account limit to 0 so no new emails are sent out.